# Links within OSIsoft PI Processbook

Tags: osisoft

I am building a Processbook using OSISoft's software. I have multiple displays imbedded into the Book. Right now, I have only figured out how to create buttons that will return the user back to the book itself, like the main page.

Is there a way to link directly to a display imbedded in the Book?

Comment: Probably belongs in SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

OSIsoft YouTube video showing how to configure a button: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyVgoYwdbNY

Summary (starting from the **Define Button** dialog):

1. In **Action** field, click the dropbown arrow and select **Display Search**
2. The **Display Search** dialog will open, showing all open PB files. You will find all the displays contained in your current book listed. **Hint**: If there are too many displays listed, try closing any other displays you might have open in the backgroun.
3. Clear the **Open display in new window** check box if needed and click **OK**.

Voila! Button.

Answer (score 0):

Way is correct to use button to link other processbook or object. you can make it more beautiful by applying some image / logo / object.